# Polynomial Time Delay Enumeration of Maximal Bipartite Subgraphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms

Let $G=(V, E)$ be an undirected simple graph.

Is it known how to list all the maximal bipartite subgraphs of $G$, without repetitions, and with a polynomial time delay and a polynomial space complexity ?

(by polynomial time delay it is meant that the time spent between the outputting of any two subsequent maximal bipartite subgraphs is polynomial in $|V|$)

Comment: Is it ok if the enumeration contains duplicates? If so, this can be done by adapting enumeration of spanning trees.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. No duplicate is admitted, we aim to list all the prescribed objects exactly once.